# NURBS surface - Finding points equally spaced

Tags: nurbs

I have a NURBS surface of degree p,q, with the control points and the knot vectors U and V. 
I need to retrieve points on the surface that are distanced by xStep millimeters in the u direction and xStepV millimeters in the v direction.

I searched on internet for such algorithm, and I found information about arc length approximation on curves, surface subdivision like in the following links :

http://www.saccade.com/writing/graphics/RE-PARAM.PDF

http://www.dm.unibo.it/~casciola/html/papers/ripIJSM.pdf

After reading those articles (for 1D), I am still confused and I wonder if those are a correct approach to my problem for 2D.
Especially the arc length seems to be impossible to calculate for a NURBS.
Would it be possible to decompose the NURBS as piecewise Bezier surfaces, and then make the problem less difficult by calculating arc length on those surfaces instead ?
Any help would be really appreciated :)
Thanks !